# Add a Tags field in WP Custom Post Types

Tags: wordpress, tags

Has anyone every found a way to display the Tags field on the sidebar for Custom Post Types? I've been looking in the codex but I'm totally lost. I'm looking for way to tag my CPT for SEO purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Tags is just one form of taxonomy. When you register your taxonomy, just set `hierarchical` to false and there you go. I really can't say it any better than it's already been said [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/introducing-wordpress-3-custom-taxonomies/). The function that will register a taxonomy for you, which will accept the parameter `hierarchical`, is [register_taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would be help.
[wordpress create custom post types with tags and categories](http://webexplorar.com/wordpress-create-custom-post-types-with-tags-and-categories/)